# Ruby On Rails: how to return a collection (or array) of values from a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a parent table called `FORMS` that has many `ITEMS` in ROR, and `ITEMS` belongs to `FORMS`. I need to grab the quantity values from `ITEMS` that belongs to the last entry in `FORMS` table.

**form.rb**

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :form
end
```

**Rails Console**

```
2.3.1 :024 > Form.last.items.quantities
       Form Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `forms`.* FROM `forms` ORDER BY `forms`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError:   Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`form_id` = 63
undefined method `quantities' for...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More memory efficient way:

```
Form.last.items.pluck(:quantity)
```